# How should I (if I should at all) implement Generic DB Tables without falling into the Inner-platform effect?

Tags: sql, database, generics, database-design, dynamic

I have a db model  like this:

```
tb_Computer (N - N) tb_Computer_Peripheral (N - 1) tb_Peripheral
```

Each computer has N peripherals. But each peripheral is different in nature, and will have different fields. A keyboard will have model, language, etc, and a network card has specification about speed and such.

But I don't think it's viable to create as many tables as there are peripherals. Because one day someone will come up with a very specific peripheral and I don't want him  to be unable to add it just because it is not a keyboard neither a network card.

Is it a bad practice to create a field `data` inside tb_Peripheral which contains JSON data about a specific peripheral?

I could even create a `tb_PeripheralType` with specific information about which data a specific type of peripheral has.

I read about this in many places and found everywhere that this is a bad practice, but I can't think of any other way to implement this the way I want, completely dynamic.

What is the best way to achieve what I want? Is the current model wrong? What would you do ?

Comment: What you are talking about is known as the "Entity Attribute Value" pattern. If you are using PostgreSQL you can implement a very efficient way of doing dynamic attributes using the hstore data type.

Comment: Does SQL Server have a similar feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of four options.

The first is to create a table peripherals that would have all the information you could want about peripherals.  This would have NULLs in the columns where the field is not appropriate to the type.  When a new peripheral is added, you would have to add the descriptive columns.

The second is to create a separate table for each peripheral.

The third is to encode the information in something like JSON.

The fourth is to store the data as   pairs.  So each peripheral would have many different rows.

There are also hybrids for these approaches.  For instance, you could store common fields in a single table (ala (1)) and then have key value pairs for other values.

The question is how this information is going to be used.  I do most of my work directly in SQL, so the worst option for me is (3).  I don't want to parse strange information formats to get something potentially useful to a SQL query.

Option (4) is the most flexible, but it also requires more work to get a complete picture of all the possible attributes.

If I were starting from scratch, and I had a pretty good idea of what fields I wanted, then I would start with (1), a single table for peripherals.  If I had requirements where peripherals and attributes would be changing fairly regularly, then I would seriously consider (4).  If the tables are *only* being used by applications, then I might consider (3), but I would probably reject it anyway.

Comment: `I don't want to parse strange information formats to get something potentially useful to a SQL query.` You do have a point. This would make reports much more difficult to do. I really liked the option (4), though. I don't think it would require more work since I don't really need a picture of all possible attributes. I can just have a table N-N and include the attributes when I need to. However, I have no clue if performance-wise this would matter much, because there would be gazillions of lines to represent a single peripheral.

Comment: @ConradClark . . . The advantage of using a database is that it can optimize those searches, by taking advantage of all available hardware and by using indexes.  What you consider "zillions" probably still fits into an Excel spreadsheet.  In that case, with a decent server, the performance of option (4) should be fine for most applications.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a question of "good practices" or "bad practices".  Making things completely dynamic has an upside and a downside.  You have outlined the upside fairly well.

The downside of a completely dynamic design is that the process of turning the data into useful information is not nearly as routine as it is with a database that pins down the semantics of the data within the scope of the design.

Can you build a report and a report generating process that will adapt itself to the new structure of the data when you begin to add data about a new kind of peripheral?  If you end up stuck with doing maintenance on the application when requirements change, what have you gained by making the database design completely dynamic?

PS: If the changes to the database design consist only of adding new tables, the "ripple effect" on your existing applications will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, up-voted, I wish I could mark both your and gordon's answers. You provided the insight, he provided the available options.

Answer (score 1):

Only one question to answer when you do this sort of design. JSON, a serialised object, xml, or heaven forbid a csv, doesn't really matter.

Do you want to consume them outside of the API that knows the structure?

If you want to say use sql to get all peripherals of type keyboard with a number of keys property >= 102 say.

If you do, it gets messy, much messier than extra tables.
No different to say having a table of pdfs  or docs and trying to find all the ones which have more than 10 pages.

Gets even funnier if you want to version the content as your application evolves.

Have a look at a Nosql back end, it's designed for stuff like this, a relational database is not.